# Conjecture about circles in plane lattices

Tags: geometry, number-theory, conic-sections, integer-lattices

A plane lattice $\Lambda$ is a set $\Lambda= \{ mA+nB: m,n \in \mathbb Z \}$, where $A,B$ are linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^2$. The set of all circles in $\Lambda$ is

$$\mathcal K(\Lambda) = \Bigl\{\bigl\{X \in \Lambda:\|X-C\|=R\bigr\} : C \in \mathbb R^2 , R \in \mathbb R_{\ge 0} \Bigr\},$$

where $\|\cdot\|$ is the usual Euclidean metric.  Let's define the function $\psi_\Lambda$, for every plane lattice $\Lambda$,
\begin{align}
\psi_{\Lambda}\colon \mathcal K(\Lambda) &\to \mathbb N\\
\gamma &\mapsto |\gamma|.
\end{align}

> *Conjecture.* There is a plane lattice $\Lambda$ such that $\psi_\Lambda$ is bounded.

I found some lattices $\Lambda$ whose circles with centres in $\Lambda$ have at most two points. Is my conjecture true in the general case?

***Update*. This question has been answered [on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244096/existence-of-lattices-whose-circles-have-bounded-number-of-points).**

Comment: One of the two: either "the circle $\gamma$ in $\Lambda$" is a defective  expression or it is not strictly speaking a circle. It would be better to use an intersection.

Comment: Τίμων: Thanks for the clarification. Removing my now useless answer :-)

Comment: @Piquito, by _circle in $\Lambda$_ I mean _a set of points in $Λ$ which are equidistant from a given point in $\mathbb R^2$_, which is exactly the same as _the intersection of $\Lambda$ and a circle in $\mathbb R^2$_. I am sorry, I cannot see the problem. (edit: corrected grammar)

Comment: All is clear for everyone, no problem. I just wanted to say that I do not share the idea of using the word "circle" to designate only a certain number of points at which even the very important center is excluded. Regards.